# What is the differnece between (binary) relation and correspondence?

Tags: terminology, relations

I'm having hard time understanding the difference between (binary) relation and correspondence.

The definition of binary relation that I know is:
*A (binary) relation R between sets X and Y is a subset of the Cartesian product X x Y.*

Example with the relation "=":
$$X=\{0,1,2,3\}, Y=\{0,1,2,3\}$$
$$R = \{(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\}.$$

The definition of correspondence that I know is:
*A correspondence f between X and Y is a triple (X,Y,R) where R is a subset of the Cartesian product X x Y.*

Example for correspondence:
$$X=\{0,1,2,3\}, Y=\{0,1,2,3\}$$
$$f = (\{0,1,2,3\}, \{0,1,2,3\}, \{(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\})$$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375164/definition-of-correspondence)
is suggested that correspondence is the old term for relation, but I'm still not very convinced, because of the examples that I gave above. Any thoughts?

Comment: In the first example R = X×Y is wrong.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Thank you! I edited the question. R is actually a subset of the X x Y not equal to. I hope that was the thing you meant by "wrong".

Comment: There is little difference.  Correspondances package the definition into a triplet while relations rely upon a verbal description which can have the disavantage of loosing sight of X and Y.

Comment: @WiliamElliot I see. by the definitions they seem the same thing, but notated in a different way. If you want, post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Ok.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little difference. Correspondances package the definition into a triplet while relations rely upon a verbal description which can have the disavantage of loosing sight of X and Y.